# Entity Framework Core Include Make All Null When Same Value Exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

I'm new to EF Core and I have a question. I am listing all of the project address with `Include()` method. It works fine but the problem is when I have same value such as multiple "Los Angeles", only the last address owner get value. The others become null. Why it happens? I appreciate for any suggestion.

```cs
public List<AddressModel> GetAllDetailedAddresses()
{
    return _projectContext.Addresses
        .Include("City")
        .Include("Town")
        .Include("Neighbourhood")
        .Include("Street")
        .Where(q => !q.IsDeleted).ToList();
}
```

I have base AddressModel :

```cs
//Table Properties
public int Id { get; set; }
public string LatLocation  { get; set; }
public string LonLocation  { get; set; }
public string FullAddress  { get; set; }

//Relations
public int ProjectId { get; set; }
public ProjectModel Project { get; set; }

public int CityId { get; set; }
public CityModel City { get; set; }
//public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

public int TownId { get; set; }
public TownModel Town { get; set; }

//public ICollection<Town> Towns { get; set; }

public int NeighbourhoodId { get; set; }
public NeighbourhoodModel Neighbourhood { get; set; }

//public ICollection<Neighbourhood> Neighbourhoods { get; set; }

public int StreetId { get; set; }
public StreetModel Street { get; set; }

//public ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }


//Table States
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
public DateTime CDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime? MDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: What configuration for models do you have?  when I have same value such as multiple "Los Angeles"  -> the same values where? Address? City? Town? What is their structure?

Comment: I have Address, city, town, neighbourhood and street configuration models. when I have same value such as multiple "Los Angeles" -> the same mean for all of them. If I have same value for any configuration model, Include() only gives last ones value and set others null

Comment: @lavitron Address, city, town, neighborhood, street etc are classes and they cannot have a value like "Los Angele". Please make it clear in the post what _`same value such as multiple "Los Angeles"`_ mean.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing more about your models and how they are related. Especially the cardinality between the models.